# golang udp connection refused on every other write

Tags: linux, go, udp

I ran this UDP client program on ubuntu linux 16.04:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func CheckError(err error) {
    if err  != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
    }
}

func main() {
    ServerAddr,err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp","127.0.0.1:10001")
    CheckError(err)

    LocalAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    CheckError(err)

    Conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", LocalAddr, ServerAddr)
    CheckError(err)

    defer Conn.Close()
    i := 0
    for {
        msg := strconv.Itoa(i)
        i++
        buf := []byte(msg)
        _,err := Conn.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(msg, err)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
```

It produces this output:

```
$ go run server.go 
1 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
3 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
5 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
```

But I expected this output instead:

```
$ go run server.go 
1 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
2 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
3 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
4 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
5 write udp 127.0.0.1:58703->127.0.0.1:10001: write: connection refused
```

tcpdump says:

```
15:28:46.453313 IP localhost.47993 > localhost.10001: UDP, length 1
15:28:46.453338 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP localhost udp port 10001 unreachable, length 37
15:28:48.453821 IP localhost.47993 > localhost.10001: UDP, length 1
15:28:48.453852 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP localhost udp port 10001 unreachable, length 37
15:28:50.454242 IP localhost.47993 > localhost.10001: UDP, length 1
15:28:50.454271 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP localhost udp port 10001 unreachable, length 37
```

Why does this happen every other time conn.Write writes instead of every time?  I'm not blaming go, I just want to learn why.

Comment: can you share how your server handle connections ? looks like it's getting blocked or something like that

Comment: Unless you have a requirement for one, it's generally advisable to avoid using a connected UDP socket.

Comment: @JimB What is this "connected UDP socket" I thought UDP was connectionless?  Where do they generally advise avoiding it?

Comment: A "connected UDP socket" has a default destination address. From the Linux udp docs `When connect(2) is called on the socket, the default destination address is set and datagrams can now be sent using send(2) or write(2) without specifying a destination address`. It's mostly just a convenience, but there are other differences; like calling `recv` will only receive packets from the connected address, and the ICMP conditions like you see here.

Comment: @JimB I would rather use a non-connected UDP socket.  Does the PacketConn API do that?

Comment: @selden: use `ListenUDP` to create the socket.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look more closely at the packet capture, you'll notice that it *is* replying to every packet with an ICMP unreachable, and you are only *sending* every other packet. If you inspect the return value from `Write`, you'll also see that no data was written on every other packet.

Because UDP has no real connection and there is no ACK for any packets sent, the best a "connected" UDP socket can do to simulate a send failure is to save the ICMP response, and return it as an error on the next write.

So the first packet is sent, an ICMP unreachable message is received, the second send operation fails and returns the error, so no packet is sent, and the cycle repeats.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
LocalAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":0")
```

or

```
LocalAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "<ip address of outgoing interface>:0")
```

This should work