# Check for server reachability in Golang conn.Write

Tags: go

I am working on an application that tries to send some data to a remote server. Once I get the hostname, I get a connection by resolving the hostname using `net.Dialer.DialContext`. Once, I resolve the hostname, I keep on using `conn.Write` method to write data to the connection.

```
conn, err := d.DialContext(ctx, string(transport), addr) 
_, err := client.conn.Write([]byte(msg))
```

Error faced: I observed that due to some issues, I was not able to ping my server. Surprisingly, conn obtained from DialContext did not complain while doing `conn.Write` and it kept writing to the same connection.

Can someone help me in how to modify my writing methods in order to get an error in case the destination server is not reachable?

Comment: What protocol are you communicating over? If it's UDP, for example, this is completely expected.

Comment: Yes, the protocol is UDP but why is it expected behavior? I was expecting the Write method to return some ICMP error in this case as the server was unreachable.

Comment: The network cannot generate an ICMP error all cases (e.g. blackholed packets just disappear), and even then it may be a long timeout before you can an ICMP error. The only way to be sure a server is receiving is to have it acknowledge the receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [UDP connection example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697958/6309)

> the best a "connected" UDP socket can do to simulate a send failure is to save the ICMP response, and return it as an error on the next write.

So try and (for testing) make a *second* `conn.Write`, to confirm that you would indeed get an error this time.